# Gridview value to a parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a Home.aspx and Home.aspx.cs

I have a gridview in my Home.aspx >>>

```
<asp:GridView ID="DataGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowFooter="True" 
                        CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Height="281px" style="margin-top: 0px" Width="100%" 
                        OnRowCancelingEdit="DataGridView_RowCancelingEdit"  
                        OnRowEditing="DataGridView_RowEditing" OnRowUpdating="DataGridView_RowUpdating" HorizontalAlign="Center" 
                        onrowdatabound="DataGridView_RowDataBound">

                        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="Lavender" ForeColor="#284775" />

                        <Columns>
                             <asp:TemplateField>
                                <HeaderTemplate>Data 1</HeaderTemplate>
                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
                                <ItemTemplate><asp:Label ID="description" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("description")%>'></asp:Label></ItemTemplate>
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="Editdescription" runat="server">
                                        <asp:ListItem>--Select--</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem>SINGLE</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem>DOUBLE</asp:ListItem>
                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                               <%-- <FooterTemplate>
                                </FooterTemplate>--%>
                            </asp:TemplateField>

                            <asp:TemplateField>
                                <HeaderTemplate>Data 2</HeaderTemplate>
                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
                                <ItemTemplate><asp:Label ID="pkgcode" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("pkgcode") %>'></asp:Label></ItemTemplate>
                                <EditItemTemplate><asp:TextBox ID="Editpkgcode" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("pkgcode") %>'></asp:TextBox></EditItemTemplate>
                                <%--<FooterTemplate><asp:TextBox ID="pkgcode" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></FooterTemplate>--%>
                            </asp:TemplateField>

                            <asp:TemplateField>
                                <HeaderTemplate>Data 3</HeaderTemplate>
                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
                                <ItemTemplate><asp:Label ID="oprcode" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("oprcode") %>'></asp:Label></ItemTemplate>
                                <EditItemTemplate><asp:TextBox ID="Editoprcode" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("oprcode") %>' ></asp:TextBox></EditItemTemplate>
                                <%--<FooterTemplate><asp:TextBox ID="oprcode" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></FooterTemplate>--%>
                            </asp:TemplateField>

                        </Columns>

                    </asp:GridView>
```

In my Home.aspx.cs, I have this  >>

```
protected void DataGridView_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
        { }
```

This is where I plan to update my data from my gridview, but before updating I want to pass the old data to a parameter so user can compare/see the changes he made. For checking purposes so I can see if it really get the data, I put the following inside DataGridView_RowUpdating (and I don't know if it's wrong)>>

```
GridViewRow row = DataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex];
string @editpkgcode = (row.FindControl("pkgcode") as Label).Text;
Literal1.Text = "TEST: " + @editpkgcode;
```

It gives me the error : **NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code**

Comment: Check this definition: `row.FindControl("pkgcode") as Label`, possibly it contains null value instead of `Label` instance.

Comment: You cannot access the label control in RowUpdating event since it's not defined in your ItemTemplate. Check the answer I have provided that explains this in detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you get NullReferenceException is because when `RowUpdating` event fires then the EditItemTemplate exists but not ItemTemplate.

Since you defined `pkgcode` Label in ItemTemplate, therefore this label control is not existing when RowUpdating event fires. But, because the EditItemTemplate exists when this event fires, so you can access the `Editpkgcode` textbox defined in EditItemTemplate.

Therefore, you should be using the following code in your RowUpdating event in order access the textbox in EditItemTemplate.

```
GridViewRow row = DataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex];
string @editpkgcode = (row.FindControl("Editpkgcode") as TextBox).Text;
```

Comment: Hi Sunil. Thanks for this explanation! It works now.

Comment: my dropdownlist is now working, I just forgot to change _as TextBox_ to _as DropDownList_ Thanks for your help!

Comment: For DropDownList, you need to first get SelectedItem and then get it's Value or Text. `string @editDescription = (row.FindControl("Editdescription") as DropDownList).SelectedItem.Text;`

Comment: Just for clarification, so every time the value of _Editpkgcode_ always change? I can't keep the original value? Is there a way I can keep the original value because I can't use the _pkgcode _?

Comment: You can add a hidden field to EditItemTemplate and bind its value to pkgcode original value.  This hidden field must be in same EditItemTemplate as the one containing the text box.  Then just get the hidden field in code-behind,  the same way you get the texbox.